# MySQL Optimizing a subquery which uses a WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql

In my query, I use a subquery which get the second last highest date of an offer for a given product.

Here's my subquery:

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT product_id, MAX(offer_date) AS sec_last_date 
           FROM t_offers AS s1  
           WHERE offer_date < (SELECT MAX(offer_date)
                               FROM t_offers 
                               WHERE product_id=s1.product_id)
           GROUP BY product_id) AS t2 ON t2.product_id=p.id 
LEFT JOIN t_offers AS o2 ON o2.product_id=t2.product_id AND 
                            o2.offer_date=t2.sec_last_date
```

It works fine, but for now there're only few rows in the t_offers table.

It will probably not work that fine with thousands or millions of rows because of the `WHERE` clause which forces MySQL  to iterate the t_offers table for each `product_id`.

How could I optimized this subquery ?

Comment: I wonder if this works really well as you say. For instance, this has no sense `product_id=s1.product_id` because it is the same as `product_id=product_id`

Comment: Yes it's true, I could remove product_id=product_id and having the same result.
However I still have a WHERE in my subquery so the pb remains the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sub queries are often not great in MySQL due to not using indexes for the joins.

However it might be worth trying a sub query with a join, rather than a sub query with a sub query:-

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT s1.product_id, MAX(s1.offer_date) AS sec_last_date 
           FROM t_offers AS s1  
           INNER JOIN t_offers AS s2
           ON s2.product_id = s1.product_id
           AND s2.offer_date > s1.offer_date
           GROUP BY s1.product_id) AS t2 ON t2.product_id=p.id
```

Comment: It sounds great ! I didn't think to put an inner join inside the subquery of the left join. In this way the WHERE clause problem seems to be solved.

Answer (score 0):

can't you just sort the offer date and get the latest 2  something like:

```
select product_id, offer_date
from your table
order by offer_Date desc
limit 2
```